# Liferay dynamic treeView

Tags: dynamic, treeview, liferay

I have a list with organizations (each organization can have several sub organization). I need to show all organizations in treeView. Could you please help and give an example?

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I need is:

```
<div id="orgTree"></div>

<aui:script use="aui-tree-view">
var orgTree = new A.TreeView({
    boundingBox : '#orgTree',
    contentBox : '#Casual',
    type : 'normal',
    children : jsonData
}).render();
```

where jsonData my json array

Answer (score -1):

Include this CSS and JS in your JSP

```
 <script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

Include a div like shown below and use AUI like shown

```
<div id="myTreeView"></div>
YUI().use(
  'aui-tree-view',
  function(Y) {
    // Create an array object for the tree root and child nodes
    var children = [
      {
        children: [
          {
            label: 'File X'
          },
          {
            label: 'File Y'
          },
          {
            label: 'File Z'
          }
        ],
        expanded: true,
        label: 'Root'
      }
    ];

    // Create a TreeView Component
    new Y.TreeView(
      {
        boundingBox: '#myTreeView',
        children: children
      }
    ).render();
  }
);
```

Please refer this link alloyui.com/tutorials/tree/   for more information

Comment: Hi ravicandy, thank you for your answer. But your example is a static treeView, but I need dynamic from the list wich I have. Maybe Liferay has something like treeModel which I can fill in java and display using js?

Comment: Also I can not use IceFaces

Comment: I would suggest make web service call write your logic in XXXServiceImpl and build-wsdd and make a javascript webservice call and pass the JSON Array in children tags in the it would render how you want